# How to truncate the view title from middle

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationitem

I want to truncate the view title from middle.

Code:-

```
self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"SearchResultWithCount", nil),  self.searchString,[self.sortedFileList count]];
```

Output:- SearchResultWithCount(61...

but want to want the title something like :- SearchRe...thCount(612).

Please help me out.

Comment: youLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;

Comment: I have use this code but don''t show any title.

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30)];
        [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [label setText:self.title];
        label.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:label];

Comment: log title string if its comming or not. and set background color to label to be sure the title is added correctly

Comment: Title string is coming and i have change the background and text color as well,still it don't show the text

Comment: Can you use buttons instead of view?

Comment: if it is always truncated so you can use string same as you want "SearchRe...thCount".

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, try the following code:

```
CGSize size=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds ].size;
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(size.width/2-120, 5, 200, 44)];
titleLabel.text = your_title_text;
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleLabel];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:titleLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.text = self.searchString
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```